# Как равномерно раскидать N чисел по K контейнерам?

Tags: статистика, математика, алгоритм

Что-то не соображу, как оптимально решается такая задача:

Есть "случайный" набор N чисел от 0 до M. Распределение примерно экспоненциальное: мелких больше.

Их **надо раскидать среди K контейнеров так, чтобы минимизировать разброс сумм чисел в контейнерах**.

Думал, надо найти среднее, к которому стремиться; отсортировать набор и брать с краёв. Но не понятно, на чём останавливаться, когда набираю сумму в очередной контейнер. Вот, недобрал до "золотой середины" 5%, это хорошо, или ещё постараться? Явно неоптимально так наугад брать.

**Upd.** наверное, задача не самая простая. Похоже на одномерную «[задачу об упаковке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B)» + комбинаторику.

Comment: Может, сначала отсортировать, а потом организовать сдвиг чисел с переваротом через число.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю условие данной задачи нигде не сказано, что в каждом из контейнеров должно быть равное количество чисел. Т.е. сумма в одном контейнере может быть из 3 числе, а вот в следующем контейнере из 4 чисел. Но! раз говорим сумма, то не менее 2-х чисел в ячейке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что сразу приходит в голову (но он вроде не такой хороший).
Начать распределять с больших чисел и раскидывать в наименьшую ячейку. Более мелкие значения будут обтесывать неравенство.

**Обновление**

Не понимаю, зачем жестко брать самое большое + самое маленькое? Сортируем по убыванию, к примеру получили `[5 4 3 3 2 2 1 1 1]`. И надо разбить на 3 контейнера:

1. 5    =   4    =   3     // взяли 3 самых больших: 5,4,3
2. 5   =    4    =   6     // число 3
3. 5   =    6   =    6     // число 2
4. 7  =     6   =    6     // число 2
5. 7  =     7   =    7     // два числа 1, 1
6. 8   =    7    =   7     // последнее число 1

Данный метод считаю наиболее простым, но, к сожалению, есть случаи, когда разброс будет неидеальным.

Comment: @IVsevolod вот я тоже так полагаю: поэтому сортирую и беру с краёв: самое больше + самое мелкое и так далее, пока влезают. Но, например, осталось 2 до "середины", а на подходе число 4. Если я его положу, будет опять ошибка, те же 2, но уже перевес. В то же время эта же 4 идеально вписалась бы, может, в другой контейнер, добив его точно до "середины".

Comment: @Sergiks, Обновил ответ