# Как уравнять суммы в корзинках ленивой перестановкой?

Tags: статистика, математика, алгоритм, балансировка

Есть массив массивов с целыми числами.

Перемещая числа между массивами, надо стремиться уравнять суммы чисел в каждом.

«Ленивые» эти перестановки потому, что надо также минимизировать кол-во переехавших, и дистанцию, на которую они переезжают. Т.е. лучше переместить 1 двойку, чем 2 числа по единице каждое. Лучше переехать на 1 массив вправо, чем на 2 влево. Первый и последний массив считаем соседними.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, каков может быть алгоритм?**

В рабочей задаче порядка 100 массивов, около 100k целых чисел в диапазоне от 1 до 1e7.

Потом предполагаю дополнительно смягчить изменения, ограничив их кол-во и разбив задачу на дискретные шаги, меняя за каждый по чуть-чуть.

> [Родственный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/374859/), но там свободная сортировка, а здесь приходится иметь дело с имеющимся набором и минимизировать изменения.

Comment: А как называется данная задача? Есть ли у нее какое-либо название? Может быть, она числится в списке олимпиадных задач под каким-либо названием?

Comment: Не знаю, как называется – а то нагуглил бы рекомендации.

Внешне, может, напоминает плоскую модель, где неравномерно насыпают в коробку шарики разных размеров, а они потом утрясаются до ровного слоя. Только тут всё дискретно.

Answer (score 2):

Я с такими задачами не сталкивался, на ум приходит только то, что тут надо строить граф, у которого весовыми значениями будет выступать сумма: расстояние + количество перемещаемых элементов.

То есть высчитать сумму в каждом массиве, запомнить среднее значение и спроецировать их номера по возрастанию. Далее смотреть и строить этот граф.

1. Взять самый крупный и из него максимальные числа, которые могут заполнить самый минимальный и уравнять максимальный.
2. Взять, который ближе по шагам к минимальному, и из него максимальные числа, которые могут заполнить самый минимальный и уравнять этот массив.
3. И т.д.

То есть в итоге получится граф:

1. 1 элемент 10 шагов = 11 (самый крупный к минимальному).
2. 1 элемента 9 шагов = 10 ((самый крупный - 1) к минимальному).
3. 4 элементов 8 шагов = 12 ((самый крупный - 2) к минимальному).
4. И т.д.

В итоге, отсортировав граф и приняв оптимальное решение, два каких-то массива у нас примут примерно близкие к середине позиции. Далее снова спроецировать номера по возрастанию и повторить процедуру. Правда я чувствую, так как решение буквально на коленке, что тут есть много подводных камней, которые тоже надо будет учесть и что-то с ними делать.

Comment: Я правильно понял, это выходит полный перебор всех вариантов для каждого числа из любой пары сосдених массивов? Какова же вычислительная сложность такого алгоритма. Там сейчас уже порядка 1e5 чисел. Дальше будет только больше.

Comment: Боюсь, вычислительная сложность алгоритма действительно может оставлять желать лучшего. Но он делает свое дело, выполняя работу по минимизации реальных перестановок чисел, плюс я думаю его можно упростить или переделать, если брать за основу идею сохранения сумм и их весов в графе.

Comment: Кажется, я сообразил, как поступать. Как вы и написали, узнать среднее, посчитать суммы. Далее считаем разницы с соседом. С ближайшим справа.

Сортируем различия по модулю от крупных к мелким. В каждой паре (разница - это пара) перекидываем числа от крупных к меньшим, пока возможно. Если после очередного броска числа разница не уменьшается - хватит.

Далее на уровень «дальше» - не соседа, а через одного. Так можно дойти до макс. удалённости, а можно остановиться на 1-2-3 перешагах.

Сейчас пробую такую модель визуализировать.

Спасибо, натолкнули на мысль!

Answer (score 1):

Общая цель "ленивой перестановки" - выравнивание сумм по корзинам, поэтому первое и очевидное действие - вычислить требуемую среднюю сумму чисел и её избыток (недостаток) по каждой из **n** корзин. Это совсем просто:

**av = sum (S<sub>i</sub>)**, **d<sub>i</sub> = av - S<sub>i</sub>** где **S<sub>i</sub>** - суммы в корзинах.

Второй понятный момент - расписать задачу в терминах потоков между соседними корзинами. Пусть **q<sub>i</sub>** - сумма всех чисел, перешедших из (i+1)-й корзины в i-ю, тогда для установления требуемой суммы в каждой корзине должны быть соблюдены следующие условия:

**q<sub>1</sub> - q<sub>n</sub> = d<sub>1</sub>, q<sub>2</sub> - q<sub>1</sub> = d<sub>2</sub>,  ... , q<sub>n-1</sub> - q<sub>n-2</sub> = d<sub>n-1</sub>, q<sub>n</sub> - q<sub>n-1</sub> = d<sub>n</sub>**.

Полагая **q<sub>n</sub> = C**, нетрудно получить следующие соотношения для потоков:

**q<sub>1</sub> = d<sub>1</sub>+С, q<sub>2</sub> = d<sub>1</sub> + d<sub>2</sub> + C,  ... , q<sub>n-1</sub> = d<sub>1</sub> + d<sub>2</sub> + ...  + d<sub>n-1</sub> + C, q<sub>n</sub> = C**.

Параметр **С** можно задать (как минимум - инициализировать), исходя из критерия минимизации суммы квадратов потоков (который не противоречит идеям "ленивой перестановки"). Приравнивая к нулю производную этой суммы, приходим к выражению

**С = ((n-1)d<sub>1</sub>+(n-2)d<sub>2</sub>+...+d<sub>n-1</sub>)/n**

Таким образом, задача "ленивой перестановки" сведена к системе локальных задач о наборе чисел с заданной суммой из текущей корзины для перекладывания их в предыдущую корзину. А это - разновидность "задачи о рюкзаке".